# Dataflow job create from template failing with error: Workflow failed

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to get started with Cloud dataflow by running the simple Wordcount template, but the job is failing without any error reason. In the past iterations, I did see informative errors on dataflow jobs, which I was able to fix, but now my jobs are consistently failing with following status in the log. [image] Job ID: 2022-10-29_04_23_45-16586439030273551039

No errors are shown, so I have no direction to try out.

Comment: Maybe you can get more details in the worker logs. Check for errors, and any other message in the worker logs that may provide more info. The "Diagnostics" tabs in the logs may also have more info.

Comment: Were you able to find any information in the error drop-down(expanding the error log) shown in the attached log?

Comment: Both Worker Logs and Diagnostics tab are empty. My guess is that the Workers are not even getting started but there is no reason listed.

Comment: Seems like an internal issue, I would advise to open a thread in Google's [issuetracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) under Cloud Dataflow component or you can open a cloud [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/manage-cases#creating_cases) describing your issue.